# Mockito varargs Invalid use of argument matchers

Tags: java, mockito

***Test***

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MockabstractionApplication.class)
public class SimpleTest {

    @SpyBean
    private SimpleService spySimpleService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test //fails
    public void test() throws Exception {
        when(spySimpleService.test(1, Mockito.<String>anyVararg())).thenReturn("Mocked!");
    }

}
```

***Service***

```
@Service
public class SimpleService {

    public String test(int i, String... args) {
        return "test";
    }

}
```

Test fails with the next message:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>   Invalid use of argument matchers! 2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

I have to use int as 1st argument and any amount of varargs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use matchers for one parameter you have to use it for all parameters.

```
when(spySimpleService.test(Mockito.eq(1), Mockito.<String>anyVararg())).thenReturn("Mocked!");
```

Comment: `Mockito.eq(1)` do the trick. Thanks! I will accept your answer in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You cant mix both matcher and proper parameter

`spySimpleService.test(1, Mockito.<String>anyVararg())`

Can be replaced with

`spySimpleService.test(anyInt(), Mockito.<String>anyVararg())`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use argument matchers for *both* the arguments, you can't mix and match there.

Try

```
@Test //fails
public void test() throws Exception {
    when(spySimpleService.test(anyInt(), Mockito <String>anyVararg())).thenReturn("Mocked!");
}
```